# How to show MapView options with flip animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

How do I show options in a mapView with that flip from bottom animation? just like the original map application in the iPhone? Like this:

[image: Like This]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Present the underlying view as a modal controller and use the transition style - partial curl. Like this:

```
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

**UPDATE:**
in iOS6 you should do this:

```
SecondeViewController *nextView = [[SecondeViewController alloc] init];
nextView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentViewController:nextView animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

Comment: Its that easy huh? thanks a lot man!! Now when I use this transition style it flips the page almost all the way up. Is there anyway I can control how much it flips? and stop it like half way up the screen like in the picture above?

Comment: The partialcurl transition detects how much of a view is in use. Create your secondary view like normal, but only put content towards the bottom half of the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIViewAnimationTransition transition = UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp;
UIViewAnimationCurve curve = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"anim" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:[self view] cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```